# listagg_distinct is giving ORA-00904: "LISTAGG_DISTINCT": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am getting Invalid Identifier error in UAT environment whereas in Dev environment its working fine. 
Below is the code snippet where I am getting error:

```
TO_CHAR(listagg_distinct(DISTINCT UNCLEANED_SWIFT_ACCT) 
    over(partition BY SWIFT_ACCT,ACTID,CURRENCY,ACCOUNT_CURRENCY)) UNCLEANED_SWIFT_ACCT
```

Dev Version:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   12.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

UAT version:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   12.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: `listagg_distinct` is not an official Oracle function AFAIK, and my guess is that this is a UDF which is defined in your dev environment but not in UAT.  The issue here is that until recently (before your version of Oracle), `LISTAGG` did not support `DISTINCT`.  My guess is that your boys came up with a UDF as a workaround.  [Read here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HT1O85E4BHSBWN93G1B3M8SI2.html) for more information.

Comment: As Tim wrote, there is no `listagg_distinct` function [in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Functions.html#GUID-D079EFD3-C683-441F-977E-2C9503089982). Additionally: calling `to_char()` on the result of a function that already returns character data makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and a_horse_with_no_name Thanks a lot for suggestions. It resolved my issue after discussing within the team. And article on LISTAGG DISTINCT is pretty much helpful for understanding.